# Do you always need an ObjectFactory class when using JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb

Do you always need an ObjectFactory class when using JAXB?

Without it I get this exception:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:
>   "com.a.b.c"
>   doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or
>   jaxb.index

I [gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953723/whats-the-point-of-jaxb-2s-objectfactory-classes) the ObjectFactory can be overkill.  But given this exception I'm guessing you need it..  but not sure why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You get that exception when you use the `JAXBContext.newInstance(String)` factory method, where you pass in the package name as the argument. This *does* require the `ObjectFactory` to be there, otherwise, JAXB doesn't know which classes to process.

If you don't have an `ObjectFactory`, you need to `JAXBContext.newInstance(Class...)` instead, passing in the explicit list of annotated classes to add to the context.

Comment: We always have the same root element.  From the root we have a big hierarchy of classes/xml elements.  So can we just do `JAXBContext.newInstance(OurRoot.class)`?  Or do we need to pass in a list of *all* our classes?

Comment: @Marcus: Generally you need only pass in the root class, yes, unless you have polymorphic associations in your annotations, in which case you need to pass those in as well. The methods generated in `ObjectFactory` can seem a little strange, and in most cases, you don't need to use them at all, you can just instantiate directly. They're most useful for creating `JAXBElement` wrappers.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of the ObjectFactory you can include a jaxb.index file which is a text file that contains a new line seperated list of Java classes.

For an example of using a jaxb.index file see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html

Answer (score 3):

I was using **Spring** and I just had to change

```
Jaxb2Marshaller mlr = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
mlr.setContextPaths("","");
```

to

```
Jaxb2Marshaller mlr = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
mlr.setPackagesToScan("","");
```