# JaxbRepresentation gives error "doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index"

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb, restlet-2.0

I am trying to create a sample test application which converts an object to JaxbRepresentation. But when I try to run this, it gives me an error.

Main.java file

```
package test_jaxb;

import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Server helloServer = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8111,
      TestResource.class);
      helloServer.start();
    }

}
```

TestResource.java file

```
package test_jaxb;

import org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class TestResource extends ServerResource{

   @Override
   protected Representation get() throws ResourceException {
      SampleResponse res = new SampleResponse();
      res.setMsg("Success");
      res.setStatusCode(0);
      JaxbRepresentation<SampleResponse> representation = new JaxbRepresentation<SampleResponse>(res);
      return representation;
   }
}
```

SampleResponse.java file

```
package test_jaxb;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Response")
public class SampleResponse {
   private int statusCode;
   private String msg;

   @XmlElement(name="Msg")
   public String getMsg() {
      return msg;
   }

   public void setMsg(String msg) {
      this.msg = msg;
   }

   @XmlElement(name="StatusCode")
   public int getStatusCode() {
      return statusCode;
   }

   public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
      this.statusCode = statusCode;
   }
}
```

When I run this on the server, it throws the following error:

```
WARNING: Problem creating Marshaller
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "test_jaxb" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:299)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.getContext(JaxbRepresentation.java:83)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:68)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:64)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:141)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:131)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.getMarshaller(Marshaller.java:163)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:216)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:527)
    at org.restlet.representation.WriterRepresentation.write(WriterRepresentation.java:104)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessageBody(Connection.java:873)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessage(Connection.java:818)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection.writeMessage(ServerConnection.java:334)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessages(Connection.java:954)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleOutbound(BaseServerHelper.java:201)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextOutbound(BaseHelper.java:425)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleInbound(BaseServerHelper.java:174)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextInbound(BaseHelper.java:418)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:695)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
May 16, 2011 7:05:12 AM org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller getMarshaller
WARNING: Unable to locate marshaller.
May 16, 2011 7:05:12 AM org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation write
WARNING: JAXB marshalling error caught.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to locate marshaller.
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.getMarshaller(Marshaller.java:166)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:216)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:527)
    at org.restlet.representation.WriterRepresentation.write(WriterRepresentation.java:104)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessageBody(Connection.java:873)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessage(Connection.java:818)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection.writeMessage(ServerConnection.java:334)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessages(Connection.java:954)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleOutbound(BaseServerHelper.java:201)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextOutbound(BaseHelper.java:425)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleInbound(BaseServerHelper.java:174)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextInbound(BaseHelper.java:418)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:695)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
May 16, 2011 7:05:12 AM org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1 initialValue
WARNING: Problem creating Marshaller
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "failure" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:132)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:299)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.getContext(JaxbRepresentation.java:83)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:68)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller$1.initialValue(Marshaller.java:64)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:141)
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:131)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.getMarshaller(Marshaller.java:163)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:216)
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:535)
    at org.restlet.representation.WriterRepresentation.write(WriterRepresentation.java:104)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessageBody(Connection.java:873)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessage(Connection.java:818)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection.writeMessage(ServerConnection.java:334)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessages(Connection.java:954)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleOutbound(BaseServerHelper.java:201)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextOutbound(BaseHelper.java:425)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleInbound(BaseServerHelper.java:174)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextInbound(BaseHelper.java:418)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:695)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
May 16, 2011 7:05:12 AM org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Marshaller getMarshaller
WARNING: Unable to locate marshaller.
May 16, 2011 7:05:12 AM org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection writeMessage
WARNING: Exception while writing the message body.
java.io.IOException: Unable to locate marshaller.
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:539)
    at org.restlet.representation.WriterRepresentation.write(WriterRepresentation.java:104)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessageBody(Connection.java:873)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessage(Connection.java:818)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection.writeMessage(ServerConnection.java:334)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessages(Connection.java:954)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleOutbound(BaseServerHelper.java:201)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextOutbound(BaseHelper.java:425)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleInbound(BaseServerHelper.java:174)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextInbound(BaseHelper.java:418)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:695)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
May 16, 2011 7:05:12 AM org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection writeMessage
INFO: An exception occured while writing the response
java.io.IOException: Unable to locate marshaller.
    at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.write(JaxbRepresentation.java:539)
    at org.restlet.representation.WriterRepresentation.write(WriterRepresentation.java:104)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessageBody(Connection.java:873)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessage(Connection.java:818)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.ServerConnection.writeMessage(ServerConnection.java:334)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.writeMessages(Connection.java:954)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleOutbound(BaseServerHelper.java:201)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextOutbound(BaseHelper.java:425)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseServerHelper.handleInbound(BaseServerHelper.java:174)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.BaseHelper.handleNextInbound(BaseHelper.java:418)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Connection.readMessages(Connection.java:695)
    at org.restlet.engine.http.connector.Controller$2.run(Controller.java:95)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please someone help!!!

Comment: Was facing the same problem but found the solution on [Stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get rid of additional jaxb.index files you may use Java class to instantiate the context:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class...)

Usually you need to pass in only single java class because other classes are "statically reachable from these class(es)" so JAXB is able to identify them.

Comment: I have a similar issue but not sure how to apply this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368029/how-to-send-a-soap-request-using-webservicetemplate

Answer (score 22):

In my case I was able to resolve this by adding a file called "jaxb.index" in the same package folder as the JAXB annotated class. In that file list the simple, non-qualified names of the annotated classes.

For example, my file /MyProject/src/main/java/com/example/services/types/jaxb.index
is simply one line (since I have only one JAXB typed class):

```
ServerDiagContent
```

which refers to the class com.example.services.types.ServerDiagContent

Comment: This is useful when you generate code as with JAXWS

Comment: I was using Spring Boot and had to put the `jabx.index` file in the /resources/com/example/services/types folder to let it work. Probably because by default, the JAXB implementation searches for the jaxb.index file within the classpath, not within the package structure of the Java source files (Spring includes the resources folder automatically in the classpath when you build and run your application).

Comment: you did it manually ? what if domain model has 100+ classes ?

Answer (score 20):

I was using **Spring** and I just had to change

```
Jaxb2Marshaller mlr = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
mlr.setContextPaths("","");
```

to

```
Jaxb2Marshaller mlr = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
mlr.setPackagesToScan("","");
```

[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55896958/234110) & [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983772/234110)

Answer (score 12):

I got this error because of a ClassLoader issue, and I was able to solve it by explicitly passing the ClassLoader that JAXB should use, so this:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(com.myexample.test.ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName());
```

gave an error, but worked properly when using:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(com.myexample.test.ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName(),
                        com.myexample.test.ObjectFactory.class.getClassLoader());
```

which is probably similar to user3243752's answer, I bet that JAXB is automatically choosing the ClassLoader from the passed in class when using the #newInstance(Class... classesToBeBound) method signature.

Comment: Or simply do: `ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName()`, no need to specify the package name

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was able to solve the problem by changing the instantiation of the JAXBContext.
It can either be instantiated with the package name or the ObjectFactory class as a parameter.

When instantiating with the package name:

```
com.myexample.test.ObjectFactory objectFactory = new com.myexample.test.ObjectFactory();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(objectFactoryMessageBody.getClass().getPackage().getName());
```

It gave the error:

```
"com.myexample.test" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

No errors when instantiating with the class name:

```
com.myexample.test.ObjectFactory objectFactory = new com.myexample.test.ObjectFactory();
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(objectFactoryMessageBody.getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instantiation of your object factory like

```
private ObjectFactory of;
```

..then the safest, most reliable way to get a Context to Marshall with is:

```
  JAXBElement<GreetingListType> gl = of.createGreetings( grList );
  JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(of.getClass());
  Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the complete package name of the where the **ObjectFactory** class is present to **declare** and **instantiate** the Object.

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty jaxb.index file at the location where it was looking for the object factory class. That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the package name of payload Java classes where supposed to turn into xXSD file, was wrong at JAXB2 plugin config in PUM file. When I corrected it the problem solved.