# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

Tags: spring, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception

I included these in the *Build Path*:

- all Spring libs
- Apache Tomcat 7.0 library

The project still fails during startup:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jun 2, 2011 11:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Jun 2, 2011 11:07:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

In `org.sprintframework.web-3.1.0.M1.jar`, I can see the `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`.

Someone on Google says that `spring.jar` should be included but I don't see any `spring.jar` in 3.x distribution.

Eclipse 3.6.2
Tomcat 7

Edit: Someone on the Spring Forum (offline) said "Automatically update dependencies" should be checked in Project Properties but I don't see anything like that in project properties.

Comment: close the project , create new workplace, make assure about the dependencies in POM. i had to face this problem but was fixed after correction in dependencies

Comment: Can you post the contents of your .war /lib folder please. Or at least everything that is .*spring.*\.jar.

Comment: Even if I added the following dependency to pom, i was still having the same error. <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> <version>{Spring-Version}</version> </dependency> What i did was as others suggested i added the maven dependencies to the deployment assembly. And When I update the pom with other dependencies and doing maven > update project, the error keeps coming. Inspecting the deployment assembly shows me maven dependencies are getting kicked out. I had to redo the above process again.

Answer (score 818, accepted):

I had a similar problem when running a spring web application in an Eclipse managed tomcat. I solved this problem by adding maven dependencies in the project's web deployment assembly.

1. Open the project's properties (e.g., right-click on the project's name in the project explorer and select "Properties").
2. Select "Deployment Assembly".
3. Click the "Add..." button on the right margin.
4. Select "Java Build Path Entries" from the menu of Directive Type and click "Next".
5. Select "Maven Dependencies" from the Java Build Path Entries menu and click "Finish".

You should see "Maven Dependencies" added to the Web Deployment Assembly definition.

Comment: That is the way you should do it, the correct way in eclipse.

Comment: I was having the same problem. But I cannot see 'Deployment Assembly'  at  'Properties' (in a module of my multimodule maven project).

Comment: This is correct, although highly annoying. Perhaps something m2e plugin should take care of, in my opinion.

Comment: or add M2_REPO into build path, which points to your .m2/repository

Comment: I was getting this error while the Maven Dependencies were part of the build. Chepech's solution below worked.

Comment: This also worked for an Ivy project (selecting ivy.xml as the last step.)

Comment: I see Maven Dependencies added to the Web Deployment Assembly definition but I keep getting the error.

Comment: The actual solution for me was to install the "m2e-wtp - Maven integration for WTP". This solution gave me a NullPointerException.

Comment: What if Java Build Path Entries contains nothing ? I'm in that case.

Comment: This issue reoccurs for me repeatedly. Is there a permanent fix?

Comment: respect :) how did you know it?

Comment: @Marcelo How to do this in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Reading through the comments and answers, I feel that the main issue is that the Maven dependency (the Spring lib) cannot be found. Usually it occurred when you forgot to add Maven libs to build path (like this answer) or you have some changes in pom.xml and *Maven libs are not updated". If it is the later case, it's best to run "Maven > Update project"

Comment: This is the best answer. A Maven project doesn't consider normal build path export tab settings. We need to use deployment assembly to move maven dependencies to the WEB-INF/lib directory

Comment: What if we don't use Maven ?

Comment: The option "Deployment Assembly" does not exist under my properties, why is that?

Comment: just after found the solution , I saw this answer that is what we need , on "Deployment Assembly" add "java build path entries"

Answer (score 125):

Same thing happens to me from time to time when using Eclipse WDT. Its specialy frustrating when this happens to a unmodified and previously working project. This is what I do to fix it in this last scenario:

1. Stop Tomcat (if it's running)
2. Open the "Servers" view: Window > Show view > Other > Server > Servers
3. Right Click on Tomcat Server > Clean Tomcat Work Directory.
4. Right Click on Tomcat Server > Clean
5. Restart the server

This usually fixes the issue you mention.

Comment: There is a bug report for that specific situation (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=365748). Eclipse developers are in need of more informations about it and ways to reproduce the problem.

Comment: good this is the flexible solution for all, this answer must be marked as answer. Good work Chepech

Comment: This is really a simplest solution for this problem. Thanks Chepech!

Comment: This did not help for me using eclipse 4.4. I had to use Susie's method remove/add deployment to tomcat. I was monitoring the tomcat deployment folder when performing the cleanings. Don't know why cleaning does not clean the the deployment folder.

Comment: Did you tried manually cleaning it? the whole trick of this method is about the Catalina work folder clean up.

Comment: Deployment assembly is the right way to do it, but if it doesn't work due to some corruption or whatnot, this cleanup actually fixes it.

Answer (score 29):

I used IntelliJ IDEA, compilation is successful, but when starting Tomcat, it says:

```
Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

In the beginning, I thought the JAR was missing, but it was in place.

Solution:
`File > Project Structure > Artifacts`, in the `Output Layout` double click in right panel `Available Elements` the library named like `Maven:...`, it will be moved to `WEB-INF/lib` in the left pane.

Accept and restart Tomcat.

Comment: This answer is not exactly relevant for the asked question as OP was using Eclipse

Comment: But it helped me.

Answer (score 27):

You could try "Clean Tomcat Work Directory" or simply "Clean..". This supposed to discard all published state and republish from scratch.

Comment: Thx for this solution! The accepted answer above didn't solve this issue for me, but yours did.

Answer (score 8):

This is surely Eclipse related issue.
The thing which worked for me is creating a new server in eclipse server tab.
Then run your application in this new server, it should work.

Answer (score 7):

If you're using maven, perhaps the project aint built yet. First do a `mvn clean package` then try redeploying again.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use at least version `3.2.8.RELEASE` of spring-core.

For Maven, set in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cglib/core/SpringNamingPolicy.html, since 3.2.8.

Answer (score 7):

If everything mentioned above does not work try the following. It worked for me.

Remove your project from the server > Restart server > Add your project to server > Restart server.

**Detailed Instruction:**

```
1. Right click on server > Add and Remove
2. Select your project > Remove > Finish
3. Restart your server
4. Right click on server > Add and Remove
5. Select your project > Add > Finish
6. Restart your server again.
```

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue for a eclipse project configured for Tomcat 7 runtime

Right click on project and go to project properties.
Click on Deployment Assembly. I could notice that my spring library jars which I created during compile time with a user library was missing.
Just add the jars and you should see no errors in console during tomcat start up

Answer (score 6):

Solution for Eclipse Luna:

1. Right Click on maven web project
2. Click 'Properties'menu
3. Select 'Deployment Assembly' in left side of the popped window
4. Click 'Add...' Button in right side of the popped up window
5. Now appear one more popup window(New Assembly Directivies)
6. Click 'Java Build path entries'
7. Click 'Next' Button
8. Click 'Finish' Button, now atomatically close New Assemby Directivies popup window
9. Now click 'Apply' Button and Ok Button
10. Run your webapplication

Answer (score 5):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, and deploy application on Tomcat Server, it says:
Under

1. File menu ->
2. Select project Structure ->
3. Click artifact then Output Layout->
4. Select your jars on the right, double click it
5. Now its in the left pane in WEB\lib ->
6. Restart server

[image]

Comment: worked for me, just not clear steps

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is a problem of Tomcat.
**Just go to 'lib' folder of your project and copy your all 'Spring' related jars into this. Refresh your project and you are all good to go.**
This problem sometime persists because tomcat is unable to locate Spring core classes.

Comment: where is located the "lib" folder?

Answer (score 2):

For me the fix was to right click on my webapp module > Maven > Update Project

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same error. I had not added the below dependency in my POM file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.7.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

But My porject used to run even before I had added this dependency. But at one point it stopped and started giving the same above error.

If any one couldn't solve this error they can also solve by this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/)

Comment: <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

Adding this helped me getting solved this error .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding **spring-web dependency** in my pom.
 Make sure you use spring-web jar which has **ContextLoaderListener** class extends ContextLoader implements ServletContextListener and reside in the package org.springframework.web.context. I used 3.0.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

I tried the

- project clean mvn
- clean
- clean tomcat work directory Automatically
- update dependencies

The only thing that worked at least temporarily was to add Maven Dependencies to Web Deployment Assembly definition

But this does not work for ever! After a couple of days it stops working. My solution was to remove Maven Dependencies, apply change and add Maven Dependencies again.

I'm using
- eclipse Juno
- embedded maven
- tomcat 7

Answer (score 1):

For gradle users, It works with following steps

1) **Stop and Delete** tomcat server from **Servers** Tab in eclipse

[image: eclipse tomcat tab]

**2) clean webapp and work directory from tomcat installation** , (Reference, [How-To: Clear out Tomcat’s cache and fix outdated JSP problems](http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2009/10/15/how-to-clear-out-tomcats-cache-and-fix-outdated-jsp-problems/))

```
$ rm -r /usr/local/AT7028/work/*
$ rm -r /usr/local/AT7028/webapps/WAR_NAME
```

**3) clean and eclipsify project using build tool**

`$ ./gradlew clean eclipse` //fire respective command for `mvn` users, `$ mvn clean package`

**4) configure a new Tomcat server in eclipse, and run the project again.**

Answer (score 1):

i too faced the same problem.... and resolved by following the below steps:

RC(right click on web project)  --> properties  --> Deployment Assembly -->  Add --> Java Build Path Entries --> Next --> select jar files which are missing --> next --> finish

Application is running successfully...

Comment: I have the OP's error, but there were no jar files missing in my deployment assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue , and I have resolved it using the steps mentioned above.but no when I have this issue again and  i try the following,

RC(right click on web project) --> properties --> Deployment Assembly --> Add --> Java Build Path Entries --> Next -->

after clicking on next its only a blank window with the options Next and Fnish disabled.What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem.

Just removed the server from configuration and added it back after restarting eclipse by adding it to the server runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution I prefer which I suited most for this situation is simply delete .metadata folder of your work space and import your projects again. If you try all other option it wont guarantee the success. Sometimes the above solutions work sometime you will spend your precious hours to fix this configuration.

One day i decided to clean my work station.I arranged the projects to their suitable folders according to different clients. As a result all got messed up. After spending a whole day it did not end up in a fixed work space. Next day I simply deleted the .metadata folder of the work space and imported all the projects again. Bingo all set.

Answer (score 1):

Put `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml if you are using Maven.
In that case, maybe it is with jar packaging

You must have Maven libs in Deployment Assembly

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this a couple times a quarter.  This time I had a minimal change summary in my git diff and tracked the problem to a reset classpath (missing my WEB-INF/lib dependency) in eclipse.  This seems to occur any time I pull in or pull out parent/sibling maven projects.

There are mentions of adding your spring jars to the tomcat web container lib - this is ok and is the way most EE servers run.  However be aware that by placing spring higher in the classloader tree on tomcat you will be running higher than the classloader level of your war context.  I recommend you leave the libs in a per/war lower level classloader.

We see the following after a truncated .classpath after a structural project change in eclipse.

```
Dec 18, 2016 11:13:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
```

My classpath was reset and the WEB-INF/lib dependency was removed.

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

put back

```
<attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
```

and you will be OK.

thank you
/michael

Comment: exactly, this happens when , <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/> disappeas from .classpath file

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Update project configuartion" messed up the build path of the project.

Fix: Open the "configure build path..." menu (right click on the project) and fix the Included/Excluded options for each source folder.
That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In many case It is java facet problem ,jdk or jre or jsp  version is difference than maven project face.

Answer (score 0):

The actual solution for me was to install the "m2e-wtp - Maven integration for WTP". The solution of Marcelo is not neccessary in that case.

Answer (score 0):

if nothing from above works, remove the .class  from the listener class  i.e.

```
<listener>
<listener-class>

org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.class

</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me ..

Right Click on maven web project
Click 'Properties'menu
Select 'Deployment Assembly' in left side of the popped window
Click 'Add...' Button in right side of the popped up window
Now appear one more popup window(New Assembly Directivies)
Click 'Java Build path entries'
Click 'Next' Button
Click 'Finish' Button, now atomatically close New Assemby Directivies popup window
Now click 'Apply' Button and Ok Button
Run your webapplication

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I made changes to my Hibernate mapping in an IntelliJ project using Gradle. Simply rebuilding the project worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I had the lib in my build path, but not in my deployment assembly. Also when I had a missing context.xml.

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the solutions, it seems the problem is always something that prevents the spring library to be loaded.  It could be a dependency problem or a deployment problem.

In my case, it was the maven repository that somehow got corrupt.  What solved the problem was to remove the folder `C:\Users(my name).m2\repository' and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the class was located in `test` package. Moving it to `main` package has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did a code pull but did not update project version on eclipse server/modules tab. For some reason, maven clean install did not delete old project folder from target and instead created new folder too.

Correcting project version on server fixed this issue.

Posting this just in case someone makes the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check also the scope in the `pom.xml` dependency , if the scope is provided that indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime.

For more details:
[Dependency Scope](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

visual solution as answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8128255/778517