# exception deploying maven/spring app in vmware vfabric tc server

Tags: java, spring, maven-plugin, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, tcserver

I had the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl). I tried adding the Maven Dependencies 
in Deployment Assembly as suggested in the first answer, but then a lot more errors come up. It is not aknowledging the libraries.

Here is a bit of the log (this same exception happens with many many classes):

```
ADVERTENCIA: No puedo cargar la clase [javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke] para revisar contra la anotación  @HandlesTypes de uno o más ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
20-sep-2012 8:16:03 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
ADVERTENCIA: No puedo cargar la clase [javax.interceptor.ExcludeClassInterceptors] para revisar contra la anotación  @HandlesTypes de uno o más ServletContentInitializers. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.interceptor.ExcludeClassInterceptors
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1678)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:450)
20-sep-2012 8:16:03 org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
```

I'm using STS with VMWare vFabric tc Server, but I have tried with tomcat and the result is the same. I really don't know what to do... plus this also happens with some apps that used to be deployed correctly.
I have tried with the same project in a colleague's STS and it works.I've compared both configurations and I don't see differences.

Any Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparing every configuration item between my colleague's STS and mine, we found out that I had to install the "Maven Integration for WTP". 
I did this by adding the software site http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/ and then downloading the software from there.
Note that this package has a dependency on the connector "m2e connector for mavenarchiver pom properties" which can be found on Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery > Open Catalog, so this connector has to be installed first, otherwise it will throw an error when trying to install the "Maven Integration for WTP".