# Tomcat server 404

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7, http-status-code-404

I have a project using Maven3 to run on Tomcat 7.

Tomcat is running and the maven project successfully deployed to tomcat; however when I visit my project link `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp` I get a 404 error.

I am wondering if I have to log in to tomcat first?

I am quite new to this set up so excuse my ignorance if I am missing something obvious.

**EDIT**

My **localhost log**

```
           Jun 10, 2014 10:51:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@c9d8da8
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4854)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jun 10, 2014 10:51:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Jun 10, 2014 10:51:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jun 10, 2014 10:51:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()   
Jun 10, 2014 10:51:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1de3ac1a')
Jun 10, 2014 10:58:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

In my **pom.xml** I have the following Spring dependencies

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**EDIT 2**

I fixed the Spring Error in the first edit by following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl) but I am still getting a 404 error. No errors on any of the tomcat logs.

My **pom.xml** tomcat plugin is

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
               <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
               <server>tomcat</server>
              <path>/myWebApp</path>
         </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

**EDIT 3**

My **web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>FindLove</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>user</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/user-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
 </web-app>
```

Comment: Loot at tomcat log. There must have deployment error.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's deployed under another context name. Considering you're using Maven, probably the version number is included, so you might be able to access at `http://localhost:8080/myWebApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` or something similar, depending on your project's actual version.

I think the Tomcat log indicates the context name.

Comment: In the catalina log there are no errors however in localhost log I have `SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@c9d8da8
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener`

So I will look at that thank you.

Comment: Yeah, most likely you're not providing the required Spring libraries in your web application's `lib` folder.

Comment: I've added my pom.xml dependencies to the original post. The spring dependencies are all available I must have some other problem.

Comment: You may have the dependencies defined in your POM file, but Tomcat seems unable to find them. Are you deploying the WAR file, or running the server from within your IDE?

Comment: I'm deploying using `mvn tomcat:deploy` and I don't get any errors on the tomcat stack trace or on maven when deploying

Comment: I added another EDIT. The error is fixed but I am still getting 404 from tomcat. No error on any of the log files.

Comment: sorry findlove was an old name I've updated I'm using http://localhost:8080/myWebApp

Comment: Do you have an `index.html`, `index.jsp` or other welcome file present? Is it configured in your `web.xml`?

Comment: I have an index.jsp but there is no reference to it in the web.xml

Comment: if I go my `localhost:8080/manager/html` I can see `/myWebApp` and running is set to true however when i try go to `localhost:8080/myWebApp` I still receive the 404 status

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us tomcat log?. It may cause by deployment problem

Comment: added in my original post

Comment: Okay I can see. So I guess another problem is about your Controller configuration. Can you post your Controller config like Spring annotation/ Spring beans configuration file, etc.