# Deployment assembly of a Maven's Springboot project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, tomcat, dependencies

Trying to deploy a SpringBoot Maven project on my Tomcat in Eclipse.

First problem: the lib directory is empty after deployment, Maven is not doing the job although the dependencies are in the Build Path.
First solution: i added manually my Maven's dependencies to the deployment structure in Property > Deployment Assembly, and this worked fine.

Second problem: each and everytime i update my Maven's project, the Deployment Assembly goes back to the original state (no Maven's dependencies in WAR) and again i have to do the job manually.

Tried everything i could, everything i've found here, still not working.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>***</groupId>
    <artifactId>***</artifactId>
    <version>***</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>***</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Eclipse Maven plugin installation just in case:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495451/is-there-a-permanent-fix-for-eclipse-deployment-assembly-losing-the-maven-depend).

I did not have m2e-wtp plugin installed, this fixed my problem.