# Multiple errors while building Spring MVC project on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

**Problem 1**

Whenever I seem to try to get my dynamic web applicaiton running on my debugging server (Apache), I seem to get the error as shown below on eclipse's browser.

[image: Problem1]

---

<s>**Problem 2**</s> (This has been solved by **Edit 2**)

<s>In my errors tab, I get the errors as shown below:</s>

[image: Problem2]

**Edit 2**

*I have removed the problems that come up in the problem tab by following the advice on [this](http://javahonk.com/project-facet-java-is-not-supported-by-target-runtime/) post. Apparently Tomcat does not support Java 1.8 as of yet. However, I still haven't managed to solve **problem 1** and **problem 3**, which are most certainly related.*

---

**Problem 3**

And finally, my console seems to output this:

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. 
Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.class
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4651)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/informaticaAssignment] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 03, 2015 6:51:56 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2142 ms
```

All things considered, I have gone through the various answers that this website and the internet seem to offer me, but none of them got this dynamic application to work. I even reinstalled all of Eclipse and the Spring IDE on my computer. All helpo will be majorly appreciated!

**Edit 1**

Here are all the dependencies that I have added through Maven:

[image: Maven Depenedencies]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't have spring-web-version.jar in your classpath . Add it and it should resolve

Comment: I am pretty sure I have added that .jar. I have added a picture of my dependencies to the question.

Comment: Is there any recommendation on where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to check that all necessary libs are in your classpath or not. If yes, you can refer this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl
```

Comment: I have already tried all the answers to this post and none of them seem to work out for me!