# Error running cucumber framework

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

while trying to run Cucumber test using Spring version 4.1.1.RELEASE I am getting a issue

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider

This was working absolutely fine with version 3.2.2 after I upgraded I see this issue. Any help appreciated

Comment: Is this error coming running a particular feature or the complete project as a whole.

Comment: I am trying to run my complete suite of functional test, that's when i see the error

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl - Please try the accepted answer from that question