# Deployment webapp on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I got a "mavenized" webapp project and i finally get my file .war
After that, i got to deploy it in Tomcat 6 but i can't figure out the context, i got this error :

```
GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) application.util.SessionListener

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.util.SessionListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4709)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

The SessionListener class is implemented like this:

```
package application.util;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        log.debug("session créée : " + event.getSession().getId());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<!-- Spring intialisation -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            application.util.SessionListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

I configured the file context.xml of Tomcat with the appropriate connection to the DB.
I use Tomcat 6 and also JDK 1.7

Comment: The "application.util.SessionListener" class is not present. You must have it either in your application's classes or your application's libs, or in the server libs.

Comment: `application.util.SessionListener ` is something which is owned by your application code like some extension of `java.util.EventListener`?

Comment: I got it Under `src/main/java : SessionListener.java` and also when i compile the project i got the class Under `target\application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\CLASSES: SessionListener.class`

Comment: It's a class Under package `application.util`

Comment: Have a look if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl

Comment: @Jay thnx but it's not the same problem in your post, he got a problem with the jar of spring but mine is with the class SessionListener.java

Comment: Can you paste what SessionListener does?

Comment: Can it be that you had your application deployed already on tomcat before you introduced this new listener? and then you just dropped new war file after introducing the new war? If that is the case, try to have a clean deploy either using Tomcat Manager UI or stop the tomcat, delete your existing war file and exploded directory, drop new war file and start tomcat.

Comment: @Jay thnx for your reply, i did it but still `Error  ListenerStart` :s

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a declaration in your web.xml like this:

```
<web-app ...>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>application.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

This means that your `SessionListener` class (that you found in `WEB-INF/classes`) must be in the package `application.util`. E.g. the compiler needs to compile it to `WEB-INF/classes/application/util/SessionListener.class` (don't just move it there).

Alternatively change the declaration in web.xml to omit the `application.util.` part

Edit: I'm not sure how to read your comments - it might already be in that package. If this is indeed the case there's two more options:

- Make extra extra *extra* sure that there's no typo in class or package name (it's easy to miss this with the web.xml declaration)
- Check if your `SessionListener` class references other classes (e.g. as members) that it requires. If *they* are missing, the JVM can't instantiate an object of class `SessionListener` as well, resulting in similar problems.
- Even (or especially) after your comments to this question: Please check the answer on [Jay's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl) from the comments. Go through those steps. It might be a different jar that you're missing, but the underlying concepts are the same, no matter what the exact class is.
- If that still doesn't help: Go through my suggestion from the comment: Eliminate the `Log` and `LogFactory` references just for a few minutes, try again. Even if it *can't be* this, it's better to have this ruled out by trying it out rather than by stating it "can't be".

Comment: thnx for your reply; that's my class SessionListener

Comment: Thnx for updating i delete the answer

Comment: Your listener references classes from `org.apache.commons.logging` - if they're not available, my second bulletpoint ("...references other classes...") would be valid. Remove those references and temporarily replace with `System.out.println` - this would rule out that possibility, or point you to the root cause.

Comment: i got the jar commons-logging-1.0.4.jar in Maven dependencies, if the project didn't recognize them i well probably get an eror in the code for this :                           import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

Comment: How do you add them to the maven dependencies? I've often seen the compiler happy about them, only they've not been available at runtime, so that tomcat couldn't find them. Check if the jar ends up in `WEB-INF/lib`, then you'll have it right.

Comment: i listed the jar as a dependecy in the pom.xml , and in the folder `target` i got Under `application-SNAPSHOT` the folder `WEB-INF\classes\application\util\SessionListener.class`

Comment: i also found the jar commons Under `WEB-INF\lib`

Comment: Hi @Olaf, sorry for my late answer, i tried it and i get an another exception, tried to to update the jar `commons` but i failed because the hierarchy dependency because he's dépendent to `lingo.jar`, i think i have to replace it but the `lingo.jar` i exported it because he's an internal lib to the project so i replace it or not ?

Comment: Jay and @Olaf Happy Christmas btw ;)

Comment: When i commented <listener>
        <listener-class>application.util.SessionListener</listener-class>
    </listener>