# Eclipse tomcat - unable to display index.jsp page

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

There is a maven spring mvc project which I imported in eclipse . The same project is running successfully in my colleague's desktop . When i start the tomcat server in eclipse, I am not able to see http://localhost:8080/test/ , it is showing as error http status 404 . I even changed the port no to 8081 and ran it again but it is giving same error . It is not able to find the index.jsp page .

Comment: Haven't you got some more details? What is actually deployed on your filesystem? Do you use a single .war file or its "exploded" content? Do you intend to deploy an .ear file, which Tomcat doesn't support?.....

Comment: I got the project as a zip file which I extracted on desktop and imported it via import project . i see the src content as below in eclipse

src - main-java - .java files / 
src - main-webapp - WEB-INF- views - helloworld.jsp / 
src - main-webapp - WEB-INF- views - dispatcher-servlet.xml / 
src - main-webapp - index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
File -> Import -> [General] -> Project interchange (for the whole ZIP)
```

or

```
File -> Import -> [General] -> Existing project into workspace (for the extracted file)
```

for eclipse to import them properly.

Do you see tomcat running properly under localhost:8080 or 8081 ? if not, then it means something is wrong with Tomcat in general, what can you see in catalina.log file during tomcat start attempt (or in the command shell where you  attempt 'catalina start' ?

Answer (score 0):

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl)

The first answer in the above query solved the issue . I was getting classNotFoundException due to which index.jsp I was unable to view .