# Unable to load org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to set up spring MVC but when i start tomcat i am getting this exception  and i am using spring with Hibernate. The Hibernate is working fine but Spring MVC is giving exception.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvspn.jpg)

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4997)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5289)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745
```

The jars i am using

1. commons-logging-1.2
2. spring-4.2.4.RELEASE.zip which includes all jars of spring
3. log4j

My web.xml code

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HTML/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/jsp/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`My mvc-servlet.xml code

```
`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pos.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>`
```

And i have searched it in class path using ctrl+shift+t **org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet** exists
My test MVC java code `@Controller

```
public class HelloController{
    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>"
                + "<h3>********** Hello World, Spring MVC Tutorial</h3> **********</div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }
   }`
```

And Please do not mark it duplicate i have seen all the duplicate question before and also tried the staff they asked but still same exception tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: What are the exact contents of your `WEB-INF/lib` folder within your war file?

Comment: i have all jar added in bulid path as well as all the jar in **WEB-INF/lib**

Comment: Please edit the question and add the *exact* contents of that folder if you want continued help.

Comment: I have added a image hope it will be helpful to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a context loader listener on your `web.xml` add this :

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

and if you are running your application from  eclipse managed tomcat , make sure that your deployment assembly contains all the jars. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl) for specific details.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue the thing i was doing wrong was i was using the web.xml of tomcat so stupid of me because i have not generated web.xml when i was creating the project.