# Maven project deployment error for ContextLoaderListener

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I am converting my project from ant to maven. The build process succeeded asda

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[Failed to load listener: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: class java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

I have checked the project Deployment Assembly and found that Maven Dependecy in added and classpath entry. My war also contains all jars under WEB-INF/lib. Can anyone help me to resolve this.

Thanks,
Surodip

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl ?

Comment: @Joachim, as mentioned I have already tried the answer of the post you mentioned and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding spring-web jar in the Deployment Assembly explicitly. I don't know is it the correct way. I was thinking that the spring-web jar will be available from Maven Dependency, as it is added in Deployment Assembly. Can anyone tell me why at the time of deployment the spring-web jar is not taken from Maven Dependency? and what will be a solution for long-term? Thanks