# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springhibernatemvc.dao.PersonDAOImpl

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, classnotfoundexception

I am having an error in my servlet-context.xml. It is saying that it can find the below classes but there actually exist in the projecct folder.

```
<beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.springhibernatemvc.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.springbibernate.services.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

It is saying that this class is not found

```
- Class 'com.springbibernate.services.PersonServiceImpl'
```

My servlet-context file is also defined in my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

I have adding servlet-context.xml to the root folder of my web app but still the error exists.

Complete stacktrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.springhibernatemvc.dao.PersonDAOImpl] for bean with name 'personDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springhibernatemvc.dao.PersonDAOImpl
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.springhibernatemvc.dao.PersonDAOImpl] for bean with name 'personDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.springhibernatemvc.dao.PersonDAOImpl
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

from Java Docs

> Thrown when an application tries to load in a class through its string name using:
>
> - The forName method in class Class.
> - The findSystemClass method in class ClassLoader .
> - The loadClass method in class ClassLoader.
>
> but no definition for the class with the specified name could be found.

The problem here is not with the servlet-context.xml but the beans defined in there. make sure that the full cannonical class names are correct and respective class files are present under WEB-INF or some library under that .

From a first high level look it seems that you are defining bean with class as 
 'com.spring**b**ibernate.services.PersonServiceImpl'

where the correct name appears to be  'com.spring**h**ibernate.services.PersonServiceImpl'

So the xml content should be like :

```
<beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.springhibernatemvc.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService" class="com.springhibernate.services.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: The classes are present in WEB-INF folder

Comment: Confirm this is what you are looking for WEB-INF/classes/com/springhibernatemvc/dao/PersonDAOImpl.class and also can you paste the latest error message .

Comment: How can I get this class PersonDAOImpl.class

Comment: It is only defined in the package with .java extension

Comment: This class is generated when you compile you source java classes, and export a war out of the source project .

Comment: So how do I add it because I have done a Maven build but the error still persists

Comment: when you do a maven build on the project, it will generate a war under {Project_folder}/target look for the war and extract that should have packaged your classes correctly,

Comment: I have added complete stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Make an entry of the below tags in your spring-context xml file:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springhibernate.services, com.springhibernatemvc.dao" />
```

if you are getting the **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener**
then, follow the below link:

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl?rq=1)