# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springFramework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener tomcat 9, maven, spring

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

My web project suddenly stopped working.

I have tried everything, added maven dependencies to class path, deleted spring-web.jar and added back, deleted tomcat and added back and etc..

Please help me I have no idea how to fix it, read all the answers for this question and nothing helped me.

> SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.springFramework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springFramework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:540)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:521)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5099)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
>       at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)

the pom.xml spring-web dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springFramework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:com/spring/web/context/dao-context.xml
        classpath:com/spring/web/context/service-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/classnotfoundexception-springframework-contextloaderlistener/

Answer (score 0):

> This Blog is telling you couple of ways to solve this issue..

[ClassNotFoundException : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-error-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderlistener/)

> this question is also discuses here you may can get tons of information from here...

[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)