# spring and jsf project

Tags: spring, jsf, myfaces

I am trying to run an ancient Spring project  on eclipse and i get this error :

```
GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1907)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

mars 27, 2018 5:51:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Erreur lors de la configuration de la classe d'écoute de l'application (application listener) org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1907)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5641)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: The error says that it has not been included d'écoute

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl)

Answer (score 2):

Well the problem is solved now, I had some problems to solve at the 
Markers tab in the bottom panel in eclipse, the main problem is :

```
Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 3.0
```

and the solution was to update the header of the 
 web.xml  :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

and then just **Maven -> Update Project ..**