# Bean configuration error in spring MVC welcome program

Tags: java, xml, maven, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I am new to spring MVC tried with a starter program, with maven project.
But it is throwing error which i am not able to resolve.
Below is files i have used and structure.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Project structure

[image]

Error on http://localhost:8080/springmvcsme/one

[image]
POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>springmvcsme</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
        <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Add Spring Web and MVC dependencies -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlets.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

spring5-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="https://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc https://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC</display-name>

    <!-- Add Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring5</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring5-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring5</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

AppController.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC</display-name>

    <!-- Add Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring5</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring5-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring5</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome to Spring MVC
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

modify web.xml and spring5-servlet.xml files are as follows,

add `listener-class` to the web.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Spring MVC</display-name>

    <!-- Add Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as front controller -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring5</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring5-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring5</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

set the full qualified package name to `base-package` in spring5-servlet.xml file,

```
<context:component-scan base-package = "com.controller" />
```

Comment: DId the changes but no success :(
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

Comment: i think above solution works for you. but get a new error at this point. please refer this url (https://stackoverflow.com/q/6210757/8700934) for `SEVERE: Error configuring application listener ofclass[org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:`

Comment: please let me know if it solves your new problem (new error)