# ClassNotFoundException with Tomcat 9

Tags: spring, tomcat

The application is a spring based web application. Getting `classNotFound Exceptions` for the following 3 classes while starting the server from eclipse:

> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>
> org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
>
> org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher

Server: Tomcat 9

1. Tried clean tomcat build directory and clean option.
2. Tried "Add and Remove" server option.

Comment: The solution here should resolve your problems https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210757/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-springframework-web-context-contextloaderl

Comment: I have tried this too, but not working