# javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: doesn't contain ObjectFactory.class o jaxb.index

Tags: java, maven, soap, jaxb, spring-ws

I've a Java Spring Web application that I need to use as SOAP client.

I'm using Maven and I've got a main module (WAR) with my custom code and a child module (JAR dependency) with the WSDLs (I've two WSDL) generated classes.

As you can see in the title when I run the application an error occurs

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: doesn't contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

This is the ApplicationContext.xml of the main module:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />          
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="wsSecurityInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken" />
        <property name="securementUsername" value="xxx" />
        <property name="securementPassword" value="xxxx" />
        <property name="securementPasswordType" value="PasswordText" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">        
        <property name="contextPaths">
            <list value-type="java.lang.String">
                <value>my.package.path.wsdl</value>                
                <value>my.package.path.wsdlserver</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

into the child module the WSDL classes are generated correctly and two ObjectFactory.class are presents in each package:

```
my.package.path.wsdl
my.package.path.wsdlserver
```

Error is raised during the Marshaller Bean:

```
    Error creating bean with name 'marshaller' defined in ServletContext resource
...
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "my.package.path.wsdl" doesn't contains ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

I've found several threads about this problem but I can't understand the issue in my case due to the fact that the ObjectFactory.class are presents (automatically created by the maven-jaxb2-plugin.

Thanks in advance for your support and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I solved changing the Marshaller Bean definition in this way:

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"> 
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <list>
         <value>my.package.path.wsdl</value>                
         <value>my.package.path.wsdlserver</value>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I needed to swtich from **contextPaths** property to **packagesToScan**