# Proper way of creating JAXB objects

Tags: java, jaxb

I noticed `ObjectFactory` class generated by jaxb compiler xjc. I read something about the purpose of it.

I am wondering what is a proper way to create jaxb objects as for my purposes I don't need this class at all.  Should I always use the `ObjectFactory` even for trivial cases or can I construct the objects via normal constructor (what definitely works ok)?

Edit: added example:

I need to create instance of `IpAddress`

This is factory method:

```
  public IpAddress createIpAddress() {
        return new IpAddress();
    }
```

Is it better `IpAddress ia = new IpAddress()`

or

```
IpAddress ia = objectFactory.createIpdAddress()
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953723/whats-the-point-of-jaxb-2s-objectfactory-classes

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the instance created if you use the `ObjectFactory` to create the instance of the domain object or just use the zero arg constructor in [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222).  In [**JAXB 1 (JSR-031)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=31) instead of POJOs there JAXB impls created interfaces with vendor specific impl classes, back then `ObjectFactory` was required to create instances.

There are times when the domain object needs to be wrapped in an instance of `JAXBElement`, `ObjectFactory` contains useful methods for doing this (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html).

`ObjectFactory` is ultimately required by JAXB for the metadata it contains.  JAXB will traverse transitive dependencies when processing a class.  Having the create methods on the `ObjectFactory` gives a single class that JAXB can use to process metadata for the whole model.

---

### UPDATE

> Ok. So best-practice-wise what would be the proper approach? (see my
>   example pls)

It really depends. Personally I prefer to use the constructors.  I have an example below that demonstrates the two approaches.

**XML Schema**

Below is the XML Schema I have used to create the Java model.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xs:element name="root" type="root"/>
    <xs:complexType name="root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="foo">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Demo Code**

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using Constructors
        Root.Foo foo1 = new Root.Foo();
        foo1.setBar("Hello");
        Root root1 = new Root();
        root1.setFoo(foo1);
        JAXBElement<Root> jaxbElement1 = new JAXBElement<Root>(new QName("root"), Root.class, root1);


        // Using ObjectFactory
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        Root.Foo foo2 = objectFactory.createRootFoo();
        foo2.setBar("World");
        Root root2 = objectFactory.createRoot();
        root2.setFoo(foo2);
        JAXBElement<Root> jaxbElement2 = objectFactory.createRoot(root2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok. So best-practice-wise what would be the proper approach? (see my example pls)

Comment: @LeNoob - Yes, both approaches are ok.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectFactory is used by JAXB to identify classes to be bound, eg

```
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("test"); <-- test is package
    Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
    m.marshal(new X(), System.out);  <-- X is test package
```

throws

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "test" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

but

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(X.class);
...
```

works OK because we loaded X to JAXBCOntext explicitly

Comment: My question relates to the situation as in example which I added to my question.